# Get embedded txt with selector-syntax

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm using the Jsoup library and I'm looking for the right pattern that can make me get the "$335" from this HTML code.

`<p class="price"> <span class="old">$670</span> $335 </p>`

Any way of acheiving this?

Thanks in advance

Sani

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:
I have not tested it yet though

```
String html = "<p class='price'> <span class='old'>$670</span> $335 </p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String str = doc.select(".price").first().text();
str = str.replace(doc.select(".price span").first().text();,'');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Valentin, however I want to use JSoup library to do so. I just don't know how to acheive that.

Comment: I have edited my answer to work with JSoup, although I have not tested it yet.

Comment: Thanks again for your fast answer, it is very much appreciated. Your example will work however I'm looking for something more consised which can get me what I want in one line: Ex: String endResult = doc.select("magic expression").text();

Comment: The `magic expression` does not exist in this case because you want to extract some text from a tag. It would have worked if you wanted to extract a plain text from a tag.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solving if mine helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

In comments on another answer, the OP asked for a one-liner.  select() only selects elements, not text nodes, but it's easy enough to grab the particular text node we're looking for:

```
String html = "<p class='price'> <span class='old'>$670</span> $335 </p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String str = doc.select(".old").first().nextSibling().toString().trim();
```

We select the `span`, then get the next sibling *node* (not element), which is a text node holding the text we're looking for.  We then convert it to a string (which just returns the node's text) and trim the whitespace.